# Как обновить Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: обновления, доступ, ubuntu

Вопрос с подвохом. У меня такая беда, мой провайдер "Ростелеком" заблокировал доступ к репозиториям Ubunu, а в http://mirror.yandex.ru/ вообще доступ закрыт целиком. Как мне можно воспользоваться репозиторием?

Через анонимайзеры зайти на сайт могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рассматривал следующие варианты в Вашей ситуации:

1. Помог товарищу (у которого отличный провайдер от Вашего) поднять VPN-сервер и с помощью подключения к нему спокойно обновлялся.
2. Сменил провайдера.
3. Позвонил бы в Ростелеком и выяснил причину блокировки репозиториев.
4. Создать локальный репозиторий, который обновлять у друзей, на работе и т.п. (могу оказать помощь в настройке).
5. Поддерживаю предыдущий пост.

Comment: почему то из дома не получается принимать ответы и голосовать за ответ. На данный момент установил репозиторий http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/7245/linux-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-ubuntu. Позвонил в Ростелеком (там обещали разобраться). Написал в Яндекс.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, если обновляться с репозиториев, то может выйти криво. Это я такой вот экстремал, что так делаю, а потом руками правлю. Лучше всего закачать дистрибутив на диск, и обновление делать с него через команду cdromupgrade, или что-то типа того, которая есть в корне дистрибутива. В 12.10 это точно работает, а в 13.04 пока не знаю, ибо уезжал из России, и только сегодня вернулся, и пока не пробовал.

А прокси и анонимайзеры - это не совсем верный ход. Там в настройках обновлений есть куча разных серверов из разных стран. Когда у меня дурью маяться российские начали, я переключился на финские.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоватся прокси серверами

Comment: через прокси не обновлялся, только на страницы заходил.

Comment: Сообщите результат, интересно, чем закончится...

Comment: продолжение истории http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/7245/linux-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-ubuntu